# The SDK has not been intialized. Got this error while running react native android application in debug mode

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk-next(version 4.6.0) in my react native project. I followed the docs accordingly but then it started giving me following error since yesterday.

[image]

I checked the other answers which suggest adding the string in the manifest file but that has already been added.